# Increase image size on modal screen

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Modal screen on bootstrap is not showing full image size.

I have tried changing the modal sizes in css, but to no avail.

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg show" id="ftl1Modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="dynamic-content">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/FamilyTrees/FamilyTreeLarge_1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Family Tree Image 1" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
            <a href="#ftl1Modal" role="button" class="d-block mb-4 h-100" data-toggle="modal">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/FamilyTrees/FamilyTreeThumb_1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Family Tree Image 1" />
            </a>
</div>
```

I was hoping that when I clicked on the thumbnail image it would display the image at it's true width and height, is there away to achieve this?

Thanks for your help as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the modal fit the image width like this...

- On modal-dialog add `d-flex` for `display:flex`
- On modal-content add `flex-shrink-1 w-auto mx-auto` for `flex-shrink:1;width:auto`

Then a custom class to reset the max-width:

```
.modal-custom {
    max-width: inherit;
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/BuCU19i1mH/

```
<div class="modal fade show" id="ftl1Modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog d-flex modal-custom">
        <div class="modal-content flex-shrink-1 w-auto mx-auto">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="dynamic-content">
                <img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Family Tree Image 1" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```